# Mocking bean endpoints with method option in uri

Tags: spring, testing, mocking, apache-camel

I have an application build using Apache Camel 2.15.3. And I'm wiring the routes using spring-xml for dependency injection. I'm trying to write a test where I mock an endpoint that is a bean and has a method option in the uri.

My routes looks like this:

```
<onException id="Exception">
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
    <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <to uri="direct:fear"/>
</onException>

<route id="happyStory">
    <from uri="direct:inTheBeginning"/>
    <to uri="bean:enchantedKingdom?method=warn" />
    <to uri="bean:fluffykins" />
</route>

<route id="scaryStory">
    <from uri="direct:fear"/>
    <onException>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
    </onException>
    <to uri="bean:monster"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${header.succesfullywarned}</simple>
            <to uri="bean:enchantedKingdom?method=hide"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <to uri="bean:enchantedKingdom?method=panic" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

And I wan't to be able to say that when the bean method warn is called then the header "succesfullywarned" should be set in the message and then when the bean fluffykins is called there should be a exception that causes the message to get sent to "scaryStory" and in this case I wan't to assert that the bean method 'panic' is called.

This is the test:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/META-INF/spring/route-stories.xml","/META-INF/spring/beans.xml"})
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("(bean:fluffykins|bean:monster|bean:enchantedKingdom?method=warn|bean:enchantedKingdom?method=hide|bean:enchantedKingdom?method=panic)")
public class StoryHappyRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    private String url = "direct:inTheBeginning";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
       return (AbstractApplicationContext)applicationContext;
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){

        MockEndpoint warn = getMockEndpoint("mock:bean:enchantedKingdom?method=warn");
        MockEndpoint fluffy = getMockEndpoint("mock:bean:fluffykins");
        MockEndpoint  monster = getMockEndpoint("mock:bean:monster");
        MockEndpoint hide = getMockEndpoint("mock:bean:enchantedKingdom?method=hide");
        MockEndpoint panic = 
        getMockEndpoint("mock:bean:enchantedKingdom?method=panic");

        fluffy.whenAnyExchangeReceived(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Bunny!");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        });

        template.sendBody(url,"");

        warn.assertExchangeReceived(0);
        fluffy.assertExchangeReceived(0);
        monster.assertExchangeReceived(0);
        panic.assertExchangeReceived(0);

   }
}
```

It works fine for all the beans except the enchantedKingdom bean, that contains multiple methods that are used in the route. A mock is not used in this case but the real bean method is called, which is not what I wan't. And the test fails since since it is not the mock that gets called in the route.

How can I get the test to use a mock for the endpoits with uri 'bean:enchantedKingdom?method=warn', 'bean:enchantedKingdom?method=hide' and 'bean:enchantedKingdom?method=panic'?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the test approach and not try to mock calls to beans.
Instead, create a mocked bean instance and use that in your test.

Define a mocked bean (by code or mocking library)

```
public class MockEnchantedKingdom {

    public boolean panicCalled = false;

    public void panic() {
        // do things
        panicCalled = true;
    }
}
```

Then declare this bean in spring files used for testing purposes

```
@ContextConfiguration(
    {"/META-INF/spring/route-stories.xml",
    "/META-INF/spring/beans-test1.xml"})
```

And in your test code get the bean and assert what you need

```
// context is CamelContext you should have access to it
MockEnchantedKingdom enchantedKingdom = (MockEnchantedKingdom) context.getRegistry().lookupByName("enchantedKingdom");
Assert.asserttrue(enchantedKingdom.panicCalled);
```

Create a different `beans-test*.xml` for different tests, and you may create the mocks using Mockito or any other library.

The route code is always the same and you can control behaviour of beans in each test.

Comment: The problem is that the example in my question is only a play example to test the principle. My actual route spring xml-file contains lots of routes and lots of beans that need to be mocked. And doing this everytime I need to test a route seems extreme. And I'll possibly need different mock classes depending on what I wan't to test.

Comment: What if you refactor your logic a bit? The important part is not test that a method has been called, but rather that the whole route has behaved as expected. For example, check the Exchange at the end of the route or that another route has been called (and mock `direct:` or `seda:` components).  
If you need to check only a method, Camel is not needed just unit test the bean.